# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{10}\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$ using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I am asked to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{10}\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$$

I am using complex analysis. Setting $z = e^{i\theta}$, I get from Eulers formula:

$$\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z + z^{-1}\right)$$

Now as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, $z = e^{i\theta}$ goes one time around the unit circle. Therefore the problem is reduced to the following contour integral:

$$\oint_{C} \left(\frac{1}{2}(z + z^{-1})\right)^{10} \frac{dz}{iz}$$ where C is the unit circle.

At this point, I don't know how to move forward. I am pretty sure I am to apply the residue theorem, and the function I am integrating clearly has a pole at $z = 0$. But I don't know how to calculate that residue, since the pole is of the 10th order. Is there another approach I should take, maybe find the Laurent series of the function?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{dz}{z^k} = \begin{cases}1, & k = 1\\0, &k \in \color{red}{\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 1 \}}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the residue of the meromorphic  function
$$
f(z):=\frac{(z+z^{-1})^{10}}{2^{10}iz}
=\frac{1}{2^{10}i}\frac{(z^2+1)^{10}}{z^{11}}.\tag{1}
$$
is not difficult.

> But i don't know how to calculate the residue of that, since the pole is of the 10th order.

You are probably thinking about this [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) for calculating residue at poles. But it is unnecessary here.

All you need is to find out the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in (1), which means you want the coefficient of $z^{10}$ in $(z^2+1)^{10}$. By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), one has
$$
\frac{10!}{5!5!}=\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2}=9\cdot 4\cdot 7.
$$
Hence the residue at $0$ is
$$
\frac{63}{2^{8}i}
$$
and by the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), the value of the integral is thus
$$
2\pi i\cdot \frac{63}{2^{8}i}=\frac{63\pi}{128}.
$$

---

[Added:] Without complex analysis, one can still calculate the integral in just a few steps using the [recursive formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_only_cosine) of calculating $\int \cos^nx\,dx$ ($n>0$) and taking the advantage that we are integrating over the interval $[0,2\pi]$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{10}x\,dx 
&= \frac{9}{10}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{8}x\,dx \\
&= \frac{9}{10}\frac{7}{8}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{6}x\,dx\\
&= \frac{9}{10}\frac{7}{8}\frac{5}{6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{4}x\,dx\\
&= \frac{9}{10}\frac{7}{8}\frac{5}{6}
   \frac{3}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2}x\,dx\\
&= \frac{9}{10}\frac{7}{8}\frac{5}{6}
   \frac{3}{4} \pi=\frac{63\pi}{128}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great explanation on the complex analysis part. Thanks!

Comment: +1, very clear complex analysis explanation, excellent calculus reference as well!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $$f(z)=\frac{(z+z^{-1})^{10}}{2^{10}iz}=\frac{(z^2+1)^{10}}{2^{10}iz^{11}}.$$

Then, $$f(z)=\frac{1}{iz^{11}}\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}z^{2k}=...+\frac{1}{i2^{10}z}\binom{10}{5}+...$$

Comment: @jakvah: I forgot the 10 at the exponent. It should work now.